# Unable to access auto implemented properties

Tags: c#, asp.net

the code in Coffee.cs goes like this

```
namespace WebTutorial.App_Code
{
public class Coffee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Roast { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Review { get; set; }

    public Coffee(int id, string name, string type, double price, string      roast, string country, string image, string review)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        Price = price;
        Roast = roast;
        Country = country;
        Image = image;
        Review = review;
    }
}
}
```

and the webpage code goes like this

```
namespace WebTutorial
{
public partial class Coffee : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillPage();
    }
    private void FillPage()
    {
        ArrayList coffeeList =   ConnectionClass.GetCoffeeByType(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Coffee coffee in coffeeList)
        {
            sb.Append(
                string.Format(
                            @"<table class='coffeeTable'>
            <tr>
            <th rowspan='6' width='150px'><img runat='Server' src='{6)'/> </th>
            <th width='50px'>Name: </td>
            <td>{0}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <th>Type: </th>
            <td>{1}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <th>Price: </th>
            <td>{2}$</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <th>Roast: </th>
            <td>{3}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <th>Origin: </th>
            <td>{4}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>{5}</td>
            </tr>
            </table>", coffee.Name, coffee.Type, coffee.Price, coffee.Roast, coffee.Country, coffee.Review, coffee.Image));
        }
        lblOutput.Text = sb.ToString();
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillPage();
    }


}
}
```

now that am getting error like

> 'WebTutorial.Coffee' does not contain a definition for 'Type' and no
>   extension method 'Type' accepting a first argument of type
>   'WebTutorial.Coffee' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

totally am getting errors for all 7 properties defined.

i also have another class COnnectionClass.cs defined in App_code file which goes like this

```
namespace WebTutorial.App_Code
{
public static class ConnectionClass
{
    private static SqlConnection conn;
    private static SqlCommand command;

    static ConnectionClass()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CoffeeConnection"].ToString();
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        command = new SqlCommand("",conn);
    }

    public static ArrayList GetCoffeeByType(string coffeeType)
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        string query = string.Format("select * from coffee where type LIKE '{0}'", coffeeType);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.CommandText = query;
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                string name = reader.GetString(1);
                string type = reader.GetString(2);
                double price = reader.GetDouble(3);
                string roast = reader.GetString(4);
                string country = reader.GetString(5);
                string image = reader.GetString(6);
                string review = reader.GetString(7);

                Coffee coffee = new Coffee(id, name, type, price, roast, country, image, review);
                list.Add(coffee);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
}
```

Where am i Wrong??? This is the video i've said... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84BdoQr4fKg

i followed him and also copied his code but getting same error.

Comment: you have a UI.Page named Coffee and a class named Coffee.. maybe it can't tell which one you're referring to.  try `foreach (App_Code.Coffee` and specify which Coffee class you're referring to.  or just use `foreach(var coffee`

Comment: Instead of watching Tutorials on how to a web page.. perhaps you should read tutorials on C# Asp.Net basics in regards to things like `Classes, Partial Classes, Inheritance, NameSpace, ..Page Life Cycle, etc` also understand Constructors and the key word `this`

Comment: I just copied the video so i didn't observed that.Thank you for your help @JamieD77

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple classes `Coffee` one class is your data entity

```
namespace WebTutorial.App_Code
  {
   public class Coffee
    {
```

and another is WebPage

```
namespace WebTutorial
{
  public partial class Coffee : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
```

Rename first class to something like `CoffeeInfo`